# How to take care of badly formed URLs, such as those containing "&#xA" and whitespaces while using recursive wget

Tags: web-crawler, wget

I am trying to crawl a mid-sized (a few thousand pages) domain using recursive wget. I am using the following command (on Ubuntu linux 13.10):

```
wget -r --random-wait -D example.com http://www.example.com
```

A few pages go through fine, but after that wget tries to download a series of pages for which the URL is malformed. When I view the source of some page, I see relative links such as:

```
<a href="&#xA;                    displayPage.aspx?arg1=val1&#xA;                  ">Another page</a>
```

These are relative links, and wget is trying to download the page:

```
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20displayPage.aspx?arg1=val1
```

and gets

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
```

On the browser these characters are not shown, when I take the mouse to such a link, the link reads nicely as

```
http://www.example.com/subdirectory/displayPage.aspx?arg1=val1
```

and so the website functions perfectly when I view it manually. Is there any way to make recursive wget work fine with a domain having such links? I could not find any post which discussed this, by searching in Google or directly here.